# Is there a function to get a single number from a multiple digit one?

Tags: vb.net

I want to compare each digit to the next to make sure that the next digit is greater than the last but it gives me a syntax error of: System.MissingMemberException: 'No default member found for type 'Integer'.'

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim repeat, chronological As Boolean
    Dim counter As Double
    For password = 134792 To 675810
        repeat = double_check(password)
        chronological = increasing_check(password)
        If chronological = True And repeat = True Then
            counter += 1
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(counter)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Function double_check(num)
    Dim check As Boolean = False
    For charcter = 0 To 4
        If num(charcter) = num(charcter + 1) Then
            check = True
        End If
    Next
    Return check
End Function

Function increasing_check(num)
    Dim check As Boolean = True
    For character = 0 To 4
        If num(character) > num(character + 1) Then
            check = False
        End If
    Next
    Return check
End Function
```

Comment: No there is not. You need to either convert to a `String` and use characters or do a bit of maths. The maths is very easy.

Comment: Set `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` both `On`. Correct and retry. Your functions should be defined as `Function double_check(num As Integer) as Boolean`. You have to re-evaluate the loops: debug these methods to see whether they check what they're supposed to *check*.

Comment: Thanks a lot  jmcilhinney, tried it and worked perfectly. Jimi I believe that you are far more advanced with coding than myself as I understand very little of your comment but I hope as I progress I will look back and fully understand your comment, thanks anyway though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the passwords as Integers, and trying to get a character from them as if they were strings.

The minimum change for it to work would be this:

```
repeat = double_check(password.ToString)
chronological = increasing_check(password.ToString)
```

This way the 'num' parameter in both functions would be a string, and you can get the character of a concrete index from it

Comment: Thank you, looks like a neat way to make a variable into a string